# calling class library function after time interval

Tags: c#

I have one class library which I made in c#.

Now I want to host this class library on some server & one function of this library should call after every 10 minutes.

I am very much unsure how to do this.

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Can you not just make another c# app that references this library and put its execution on a timer?

Comment: But this function should run 24*7 365 days & not only when some one opens my website on browser.

Comment: I was suggesting a WPF or winforms or console app rather than a webpage.  But making a windows service or WCF service is a fine direction as well.  At any rate, it'll be another app that you write that executes it.  There might be some 3rd party stuff that'd do that for you, but blech.  Easy enough to write your own.

Comment: does web hosting servers support Windows service hosting ?

Comment: You wouldnt use IIS to host a windows service, you'd use windows.  WCF service would be hosted in IIS however.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I misunderstood.  You are asking about your web hosting SERVICE.  Depends on the service.  You'd probably be better off contacting them and asking them what permissions you have to run locally.

Comment: How does WCF service can do this thing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54305/discussion-between-vaibhav-shah-and-paqogomez).

Answer (score 0):

Turn the class into a console .exe and use windows scheduler to fire the exe every 10 minutes